# How to effectively kill the 'spider' boss in Beat Hazard ultra?

Tags: beat-hazard

I don't know what is its name, but that is a very annoying boss, it looks like a starfish. I can't finish my Lux Artena song due to that bastard.

It has many "arms" that shoot red projectiles (undestroyable) or yellow missiles toward me, and after taking some damage, it keeps rolling and being invincible. Sometimes it expands and shoots at me, but as soon as I shoot it back, it is invincible again.

Is there any pattern or effective way to destroy it? It keeps survive even after I killed the next boss.

Comment: The starfish-looking one? Pretty much just shoot it any time it's not curled up, and *don't* shoot it when it *is* curled up (it reflects attacks). Ideally use the Ultra Beam or Micro-Missiles to help kill it faster when it's uncurled.

Comment: Yes, that one, looks like starfish. The problem is, it always curls up, so I can't have time to shoot it. As soon as I shoot it, it becomes invincible immediately. One time I kept shooting at it in its invincible form, and made it inactivate to the end of the song, but it's too hard, as it deflects my bombs and bullets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about this boss :

[image: ultra spider boss]

Then the easiest strategy would be to stay as far as possible from it, because once it gets near you, it curls up into an invincible ball, making it impossible to kill.

(Note that there's a **certain distance** where it curls up into a ball, just **stay out** of that range.)

Also, you could unload your bombs and powerups on the boss (especially with the micro-rockets) when its at long range, sometimes I can down one of these spider bosses in the first 10s when it appears by unloading 1 micro-rocket powerup and just constantly shooting it at range.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just finished my song. So it is the RANGE that matters, I thought that was about the damage it takes or the time it being attacked. Very useful information!

Comment: Glad you made it! :)

Answer (score 0):

on survival the spider boss tends to become harder and harder and sometimes even 2 can spawn. in order to effectively survive I go close to one of the legs, kill the lasers it has attached completely with damage and duck in the space between the legs so I avoid taking much damage. this strategy implies that you can see the terrain well and react to the leg movement [if you reach high scores on survival you will get used to it]. at some point power ups become essential but the only thing I can really advise you is to play as aggressive as possible, regardless of initial death ratio. the more aggressive you play you will learn to react to changes in songs and higher difficulties.

ps: never be scared of stuff, it's your music so you gotta rock